# Rasssbery pi pico bricked

Tags: pi-pico

So, I own a Raspberry Pi pico that has a broken BOOTSEL button. Beacuse I had micropython installed previosuly, I reset the pico with the command: machine.bootloader(). Then I flashed the fuzix.uf2 file, and now it doesn't have a serial port or any sign of life. (as I read, fuzix is a unix os for the pico). Can anyone help me? (I tried connecting it with different usb cables, with different softwarem but nothing.) I researched, and I found out that I needed to flash a filesystem.uf2 file too. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: did you follow [these instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/how-to-get-started-with-fuzix-on-raspberry-pi-pico/) - you'll need a microSD breakout for the pico, of course

Comment: No, i didn't know. So, can i unbrick it? (Again, i just flased the fuzix.uf2 file and the pico has the BOOTSEL button broken and cannot be pressed.)

Comment: If you didn't know you needed that breakout board, what instructions did you even follow?

Comment: http://cowlark.com/2021-03-10-fuzix-pi-pico/index.html